# Array index out of bounds when there are a character repeat immediately after another (Java)

Tags: java, methods, indexing, out

The error line is 13. The error is Array index out of bound.
http://pastebin.com/L3FtzarH

The method is to look for a character into a string, and it works fine except when there are repeat characters immediately next to the same character, for example in the word "Rabbit" give me a error with the letter "b" cause it's twice and next to the same letter.

I'm doing the hangman game.
I multiply index by to for the blank spaces. For example: if the secret word is "cat" then it will appear 3 underscores: "_ _ _ " that underscore string has 6 characters, so if the letter is A (index 1 in the world "cat") I multiply by 2 to fill the right place in the string
underscores: "_ A _ "

**Edit 1, Your Code:**

```
   public void buscarLetra() {
      chequearif = false;
      string = "";
      letra = letraEscogida.toCharArray();
      System.out.println("la letra pasa a char:" + letra[0]);
      int index = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < (palabraElegida.length()); i++) {
         if (palabraElegida.substring(i, i + 1).equals(letraEscogida) == true) {
            if (chequearif == true) {
               string = "";
               index = palabraElegida.indexOf(letraEscogida, index + 1);
               index *= 2;
               arrayGuiones[index] = letra[0];
               System.out.println("segundo index: " + index);
               index = 0;
            }
            index = palabraElegida.indexOf(letraEscogida);
            index *= 2;
            System.out.println("primer index: " + index);
            arrayGuiones[index] = letra[0];
            for (int j = 0; j < arrayGuiones.length; j++) {
               string += arrayGuiones[j] + "";
            }
            lbl_palabra.setText(string);
            chequearif = true;
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: Please post your code here in the forum, not in a link.

Comment: Btw: You make it way too complex when including the blanks between the underscores in your calculation. Just calculate based on the actual characters, then format required to your needs (e.g. include blanks between all characters).

Comment: What is the exact error? What index is it trying to read?

Comment: I din't see so complex including the blanks, it just multiply index by 2... but well I did it as you say @home and is working perfectly, thanks.

Comment: But i'd like to undestand why when I include the spaces gave me an error. By my calculations the index never exceeded the length of the string... and thats the run time error that gave me.

Comment: @Aikanáro: That's why I recommended to remove the blanks from your calculation :-) I do not know how you initialize `arrayGuiones`, so I can't really help. Mybae you can update your code.

Comment: This is how it was before, including the blanks:

`for(int i=0; i<palabraElegida.length(); i++){
 guionesBajos += "_ ";
}
arrayGuiones = guionesBajos.toCharArray();`

palabra Elegida is chosen from an array with the secrets words.

Comment: I forgot to say arrayGuiones is a char array: `private char arrayGuiones[];`

Comment: If you are trying to debug your application, what do you see when you step through your code using a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `if (chequearif == true) {` block, you try to use `index` in an `indexOf()` call. You're trying to check for more occurrences after the first occurrence, which you think `index` points to, but you've forgotten that you've previously multiplied index by 2. It's therefore pointing somewhere beyond the second occurrence, so `indexOf()` returns -1. You double that to -2, and then try to say `arrayGuiones[index]`, which will obviously never work with a negative index.

Comment: Excelent, so what I have to do it's divide index by 2, to not change index.